# I deployed to CloudFoundry, now what? (Excuse my ignorance)

Tags: cloud-foundry

I realize CloudFoundry is still in beta and I'll admit to being moderately ignorant when it comes to this level of cloud computing but here's my question:  I create an app, everything works, I upload it to CF.  Now what?  I want to launch my app in the wild.  I want users to not see a CF URL.

Here are some pieces I do know, but I'm not getting the entire picture.

I know I can map a URL to an app.  So presumably that's just some DNS routing happening.  But other than that, is it safe at this point to bet the farm on CF and, for example, launch of startup using it?  At what point am I going to realize I need to move to something like RackSpace (or whatever) and is it possible to take my CF VM and just move it?

Overall, I just don't fully understand what we're getting with CF other than a quick way to deploy a demo application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point, if you need a custom domain, you need to configure an external proxy and from there route the traffic to your CF.com URL. [This](http://henryk-konsek.blogspot.co.il/2012/05/custom-domain-for-application-deployed.html) is a good example.

But the advantage of CloudFoundry is that it is entirely open source. You can always move your app to a compatible service provider, for example [AppFog](http://www.appfog.com/), with not much more than a simple `push`.

You could even deploy your own CF instance/server on Rackspace.

Comment: Got it!  Thanks.  Makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that there is still no support for external domain mapping on Cloud Foundry. Here is another example that uses a Python reverse proxy running on Google AppEngine. This works well. http://programming.mvergel.com/2011/11/cloud-foundry-and-custom-domain.html

Answer (score 0):

Right now, CloudFoundry.com doesn't offer domain mapping. You might expect that it will do so in a future fully-supported paid version, but as you note, right now it is still in beta.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I am running a startup B2B product on CloudFoundry.
I have deployed the open source version on our own infrastructure though, I keep a close watch on changes and even review other people's commits.
That's a significant investment in terms of learning and time, but in my opinion it's worth it.